# Docker Image "in use" What does it really mean?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-desktop

I am getting the following output in my Docker Desktop GUI. What does the `IN USE` mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As described on the [official documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dashboard/#explore-your-images):

> It also displays `In Use` tags next to images used by running and stopped containers. This allows you to review the list of images and use the `Clean up images` option to remove any unwanted images from the disk to reclaim space.

Basically `In Use` means that the image is being used by an existing container and that the clean operation **will not** remove it automatically.

Any image **not** in use, will be purged as part of any clean action to save space.